# Second order approximation of first derivative gives odd results

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

Assume I want to find the second order approximation of the first derivative in 0 of a function $f(x)$ (not defined for $x<0$). I will use the formulation for the forward derivative:

$f'(0)\approx \frac{-3f(0)+4f(h)-f(2h)}{2h}$

where $h$ is the step in the regular grid I am using. Now assume that the values of the function are:
$f(0)=0$, $f(h)=5$, $f(2h)=25$.
The function is clearly monotonically increasing and the first derivative in 0 is expected to be positive but, from the formula above, I get a negative value.

What am I missing? Does the issue all lie in the error (that I neglected)?

Comment: When you say "the formulation", I'm not sure that's the right way to think about this. Assuming your calculations are correct, your weird result could simply be a function of the particular way you approximated the first derivative. Just as there are lots of ways to approximate a function, there are lots of ways to approximate its derivative, even in only one direction.

Comment: For a function like $5^x$ a step size of $h=1$ is just too large. The error term $\sim \ln(5)^35^hh^2$ should be smaller than the result, so $\ln(5)h<0.5$ is necessary to start to get good results.

Comment: @LutzL, I was not meaning $5^x$, my third point could have also been 23, but yes, the derivative is apparently too large to get good results. Thanks!

Comment: I was just looking for a simple growing function that had the same type of growth in value and first derivative. All other interpolations will have the same type of behavior, either a rapid oscillation so that the negative derivative is correct, or rapid growth in the higher order derivatives so that the error term is large.

Answer (score 1):

A difference quotient with three terms should be *exact* for quadratics. You can even use this fact to derive difference quotients. So, let's fit a quadratic to the points $\{(0,0),(h,5),(2h,25)\}$; we find that
$$
f(x) = \frac{15 x^2}{2 h^2}-\frac{5 x}{2 h}.
$$
It's easy enough to check that this quadratic passes through the desired points. It's also easy to check that
$$
f'(0)=\frac{4 f(h)-f(2 h)-3 f(0)}{2 h}=-\frac{5}{2 h}
$$
and, in particular, that the derivative is negative when $h>0$. In fact, it grows in absolute value as $h\searrow0$.

Answer (score -1):

Try 
    $$ f'(0)\approx \frac{(2-h)f(2h)-(4-4h)f(h) +(2-3h)f(0)}{2h^2}.$$

Comment: That's a difference quotient for $f''(h)$.

Answer (score -1):

Using
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+O(h^3)$,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{-3f(0)+4f(h)-f(2h)}{2h}
&=\dfrac{-3f(0)+4(f(0)+hf'(0)+h^2f''(0)/2+O(h^3))-(f(0)+2hf'(0)+4h^2f''(0)/2+O(h^3))}{2h}\\
&=\dfrac{2hf'(0)-3h^2f''(0)/2+O(h^3)}{2h}\\
&=f'(0)-3hf''(0)/2+O(h^2)\\
\end{array}
$

so the approximation goes
in the opposite direction
than $f''(0)$.

Comment: The second derivative terms cancel, that's why this is a second order derivative approximation. You will need the third derivative term to get the coefficient for the leading error term.